# Continuously adding data to TextView freezes my app

Tags: android, mobile, textview, buffer

I'm developing an android application in which I have a thread that continuously generates data to be appended in a `Textview`, I use an `Handler` for this but after 1 or 2 secs my app just freezes.

The code is something like:

```
private class UpdateTextRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private String mBuffer = "";

    public void addLine( String line ) {
        mBuffer += line + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        mTextView.setText( mBuffer );
    }
}
```

and in the thread a method from a custom interface is called every 0.5/1 sec :

```
    public void onMyCustomEvent( String data )
    {
      // mUpdater is an instance of UpdateTextRunnable
      mUpdater.addLine( data );
      // mHandler is an instance of Handler inside the main activity
      mHandler.post( mUpdater );
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ? :)
Thanks

Comment: onMyCustom event is called as expected, so the addLine ... by the app is freezed :S

Comment: and a lot of "D/dalvikvm(4831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms"

Comment: looks like you are updating entire text of `TextView` each time. Might be good to append instead.

Comment: Try `getEditableText()` and append to that, but i doubt it will update `TextView`.

Comment: it's updating, but the problem persists ... i thinks it's a matter of how big the content is

Comment: nope, i'm sure those operations are executed synchronously

Comment: check number 4 tutorial [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_handler) , This code updates a progressBar from other thread using a handler. Use the same pattern for your `TextView`. Other approaches also shown here.

Comment: wingman, i've already tried it

Answer (score 0):

try [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of the String.

Example:

```
private class UpdateTextRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private StringBuilder mSB = "";

    public void addLine(String line) {
        mSB.append(line + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText(mSB.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder is already a CharSequence btw, no need for the #toString().

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188295/how-to-change-a-textview-every-second-in-android