# Update TextView Every Second

Tags: android, date, time, textview, clock

I've looked around and nothing seems to be working from what I've tried so far...

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deskclock);

    TextView tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    TextView tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    String time = "hh:mm"; // 12:00
    tvTime.setText(DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));

    String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy"; // 01 January 2013
    tvDate.setText(DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
```

I basically want the setText methods to update or refresh every second or so, so my clock actually works like it should do. I've seen methods like handlers and run and nothing worked so any help with this would be great thanks. :)

Comment: "Ive seen things like handlers and the run method and nothing worked" - what exactly does "nothing worked" mean?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Add following code in your onCreate() method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // update TextView here!
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};

thread.start();
```

This code starts an thread which sleeps 1000 milliseconds every round.

Comment: Working now thanks so much. :) Id vote up you but im not high enough reputation sorry

Comment: Oh one thing, is it 'safe' so to speak to set it to 500 milliseconds instead of 1000?

Comment: This method is not good at all, it makes the "MAIN" thread to sleep for 1000, which is detrimental!

Comment: I use this, But getting issue when i come back to this activity my second difference are increase make it 2 to 5 and more..Like 1St time 00:01,00:02,00:03, 2nd Time 00:01, 00:03,00:05, 3rd time 00:01,00:05, and random goes on. Can you please help me?

Comment: Perfect. Works as it should.

Comment: Please, don't leave any exceptions unhandled like that.

Comment: @sorry_I_wont I guess your comment is not valid any more since last edit?

Comment: Battery usage problem, Prefer to use service

Answer (score 30):

It's a very old question and I'm sure there are a lot of resources out there. But it's never too much to spread the word to be at the safe side. Currently, if someone else ever want to achieve what the OP asked, you can use: `android.widget.TextClock`.

TextClock documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html).

Here's what I've used:

```
<android.widget.TextClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timeZone="GMT+0000" <!--Greenwich -->
    android:format24Hour="dd MMM yyyy   k:mm:ss"
    android:format12Hour="@null"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want to show time on textview then better use [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) or [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html)

**Using Chronometer**:This was added in API 1. It has lot of option to customize it.

`Your xml`

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

`Your activity`

```
Chronometer mChronometer=(Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
mChronometer.start();
```

**Using TextClock**: This widget is introduced in API level 17. I personally like Chronometer.

`Your xml`

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#d41709"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Thats it, you are done.

You can use any of these two widgets. This will make your life easy.

Answer (score 19):

Extending @endian 's answer, you could use a thread and call a method to update the TextView. Below is some code I made up on the spot.

```
java.util.Date noteTS;
String time, date;
TextView tvTime, tvDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deskclock);

    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateTextView();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
}

private void updateTextView() {
    noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    String time = "hh:mm"; // 12:00
    tvTime.setText(DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));

    String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy"; // 01 January 2013
    tvDate.setText(DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
}
```

Comment: when activity stops i.e. in onStop(), it should also be stopped

Answer (score 7):

You can use Timer instead of Thread. This is whole my code

```
package dk.tellwork.tellworklite.tabs;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import dk.tellwork.tellworklite.MainActivity;
import dk.tellwork.tellworklite.R;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    Button chooseYourAcitivity, startBtn, stopBtn;
    TextView labelTimer;
    int passedSenconds;
    Boolean isActivityRunning = false;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_home);

        chooseYourAcitivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseYourActivity);
        chooseYourAcitivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //move to Activities tab
                switchTabInActivity(1);
            }
        });

        labelTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.labelTime);
        passedSenconds = 0;

        startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isActivityRunning) {
                    //pause running activity
                    timer.cancel();
                    startBtn.setText(getString(R.string.homeStartBtn));
                    isActivityRunning = false;
                } else {
                    reScheduleTimer();
                    startBtn.setText(getString(R.string.homePauseBtn));
                    isActivityRunning = true;
                }
            }
        });

        stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timer.cancel();
                passedSenconds = 0;
                labelTimer.setText("00 : 00 : 00");
                startBtn.setText(getString(R.string.homeStartBtn));
                isActivityRunning = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void reScheduleTimer(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new myTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    private class myTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            passedSenconds++;
            updateLabel.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    private Handler updateLabel = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.handleMessage(msg);

            int seconds = passedSenconds % 60;
            int minutes = (passedSenconds / 60) % 60;
            int hours = (passedSenconds / 3600);
            labelTimer.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
        }
    };

    public void switchTabInActivity(int indexTabToSwitchTo){
        MainActivity parentActivity;
        parentActivity = (MainActivity) this.getParent();
        parentActivity.switchTab(indexTabToSwitchTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This Code work for me..

```
//Get Time and Date
private String getTimeMethod(String formate)
{
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formate);
    String formattedDate= dateFormat.format(date);
    return formattedDate;
}

//this method is used to refresh Time every Second
private void refreshTime() //Call this method to refresh time
{
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtV_Time.setText(getTimeMethod("hh:mm:ss a")); //hours,Min and Second with am/pm
                    txtV_Date.setText(getTimeMethod("dd-MMM-yy")); //You have to pass your DateFormate in getTimeMethod()          
                };
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);//1000 is a Refreshing Time (1second)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

java 8 lamdas:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            //code here...
            String str = getDeltaTimeHumanString(instant,Instant.now()) 
            myTextView.setText(str);
        });
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

easy

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `TimerTask` for that.

Here is an method

```
private void setTimerTask() {
    long delay = 3000;
    long periodToRepeat = 60 * 1000; /* 1 mint */
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 //   do your stuff here.
                }
            });
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextSwitcher` (for nice text transition animation) and timer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you just used an AsyncTask running using a Timer something like this

```
 Timer LAIATT = new Timer();
    TimerTask LAIATTT = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            LoadAccountInformationAsyncTask LAIAT = new LoadAccountInformationAsyncTask();
            LAIAT.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    };
    LAIATT.schedule(LAIATTT, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I you use **Kotlin** this way can help you:

```
val thread: Thread = object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    while (!this.isInterrupted) {
                        sleep(1000)
                        runOnUiThread {
                            // update TextView And Random number here!
                            val rnds = (0..7).random()
                            tvBanner.text = textBanner[rnds]
                            
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                }
            }
        }


thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working perfectly**

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                      // do something
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }.start();
```