# Android - Update TextView with a value at a time [10 values]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Thanks so much for your help, the only problem is i changed the delay to 10000 because i have to display each question for 10 seconds but when i launch it the first question's display is delayed by 10 seconds as well and i don't want that to happen to the first question.. i need your 
   help

```
'handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            int firstinteger = random.nextInt(100);
            int secondinteger = random.nextInt(100);
             int operator = rand.nextInt(4);
             String operand = "";
            //do something
            count++;
            switch (operator) {
                // cases = operator;

                case 0:

                    bothIntegers = firstinteger + secondinteger;
                    operand = "+";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    bothIntegers = firstinteger - secondinteger;
                    operand = "-";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    bothIntegers = firstinteger * secondinteger;
                    operand = "*";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    bothIntegers = firstinteger / secondinteger;
                    operand = "/";

                    break;
            }
            String result = firstinteger + "" + operand + "" + secondinteger + " = ";
            textView.setText(result.toString());
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            if(count == 10){
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }
        }
    }, delay);'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814714/update-textview-every-second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int count = 0;`//global variable

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //do something
                Log.e("XXX", String.valueOf(count));
                count = count + 1;
                if (count != 10) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: i'm sorry i've posted a wrong version at the end can you review it please

Comment: Add `String result = firstinteger + "" + operand + "" + secondinteger + " = ";
              textView.setText(result.toString());` into //do something

Comment: Not use `for`, add count++ in `run()` method. when `count == 10`, you can stop `handler`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, the only problem is i changed the delay to 10000 because i have to display each question for 10 seconds but when i launch it the first question's display is delayed by 10 seconds as well and i don't want that to happen to the first question.

Comment: `int count = 0;`

final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //do something
                Log.e("XXX", String.valueOf(count));
                count = count + 1;
                if (count != 10) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            }
        }, 0);