# Thread in Fragment only called once

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread

I am trying to implement a thread that changes something on the UI in a `Fragment`. Therefore I need to refer to the main thread. 
Based on my research, I've found that the following code should do the trick:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(menuActivity, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This will execute only once though, even if the `Looper` should normally keep the thread alive. Trying to invoke `Looper.prepare()` inside the `Handler` will cause a `RuntimeException` as only one `Looper` is allowed per thread.
**Edit: My goal is to update a TextView permanently each second.**

I have also tried the following:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            menuActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("-----------TEST");
                }

            }); 
        }
    };
t.start();
```

But this will execute only once too.

I've also read [this article](https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93), but I guess my first snippet of code is just a shorter version of the code shown in the article.

Where may my mistake be in any of these snippets of code?

This question is not a duplicate, due to the fact that I presented a totally different snippet of code which is the base of the problem I had. Furthermore, the Looper is explained more in depth in this thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update TextView Every Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814714/update-textview-every-second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to update a text view repeatedly after 1 seconds. Here is a simple demo I just write.

**Mockup screen**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_money"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="startUpdateTextViewMoney"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="stopUpdateTextViewMoney"
            android:text="Stop" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_money"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="setMoney"
            android:text="SET MONEY" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int UPDATE_TEXT_MONEY_INTERVAL = 1000;

    private Handler mMainHandler;

    private TextView mTextViewMoney;
    private TextView mEditTextMoney;

    private String money;

    private Runnable mUpdateTextViewMoneyTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(money)) {
                mTextViewMoney.setText(String.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()));
            } else {
                mTextViewMoney.setText(money);
                money = null;
            }
            mMainHandler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_TEXT_MONEY_INTERVAL);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewMoney = findViewById(R.id.text_view_money);
        mEditTextMoney = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_money);

        mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopUpdateTextViewMoney(null);
    }

    public void startUpdateTextViewMoney(View view) {
        mMainHandler.post(mUpdateTextViewMoneyTask);
    }

    public void stopUpdateTextViewMoney(View view) {
        mMainHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTextViewMoneyTask);
    }

    public void setMoney(View view) {
        String money = mEditTextMoney.getText().toString();
        this.money = !TextUtils.isEmpty(money) ? money : "";
    }
}
```

- When users press Start button, the app will start updating text view each second
- When users press Stop button, the app will stop updating the text view.
- If users want to set a new money to display in the next time, just enter in the edit text then press Set Money.

Comment: Would you suggest using postDelayed instead of using a Timer as @Coeus.D suggested?

Comment: My suggestion is using Handler. You can find details here http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html

Comment: I have implemented your code now, but one clear problem is that whenever you reopen the fragment, you post mutliple runnables again and again.

Comment: Basically you always create a similar runnable and post it. How can I prevent this without cancelling the runnable? It should continue in background .

Comment: What do you mean when you say "should continue in the background"? Background mean you press home button or you remove the app from recents screen?

Comment: What do you mean "reopen the fragment", Can you give me your scenario when you want to update a text view in the background?

Answer (score 0):

> This will execute only once though, even if the `Looper` should normally
>   keep the thread alive.

You seem to be confused about the `Looper`'s purpose/functionality. The `Looper` *is* keeping the thread alive. If the main thread was not kept alive, your application would exit. The `Looper` does *not*, however, provide repeated execution of the `Runnable`s posted to the `Handler`/`Thread` which it is associated with. Each `Runnable` is executed exactly once. If you want to execute the same `Runnable` multiple times, you must post it multiple times. For example:

```
Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable doToast = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(menuActivity, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
mainThreadHandler.post(doToast); // Queue the first execution of the code in the Runnable's run() method. 
mainThreadHandler.post(doToast); // Queue the second execution of the code in the Runnable's run() method.
```

Comment: Imagine a TextView displaying money, which has to be update infinite amount of times, with a Thread.sleep(1000), how would you achieve this with the given code? I am certain that you cannot simply wrap the .post() in a while-loop.

Comment: @ProgFroz Well, you didn't really say what you ultimately wanted to do :). I explained why what you had didn't do what you said you _expected_ it to :).

Comment: Yeah thats why I added my goal earlier on after you said that ^^

Comment: Based on the edit, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14814714/1214974